# Invalid Hook Call when using react-hook-form useForm() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

type RegisterFormData = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
};
const Register = () => {
  const { register } = useForm<RegisterFormData>();
  console.log(register);
  return (
    <form className="flex flex-col gap-5">
      <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold">Create an Account</h2>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-5 md:flex-row">
        <label className="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold">
First Name
          <input className="border rounded w-full py-1 px-2 font-normal"></input>
        </label>
        <label className="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold">
          Last Name
          <input className="border rounded w-full py-1 px-2 font-normal"></input>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I am using react hook form so when I initialize `useForm` hook it showed that ... Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React).

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: I suppose the obvious question is whether any of those three reasons applies to you.

Comment: I just created a fresh CRA locally and your code runs flawlessly.  Also created a [React Playground](https://playcode.io/1765014) project and it also works.  Only change I made to your code was add the export.  So I suppose you either have mismatching version of React things (error bullet #1) or have multiple copies of React in your project (error bullet #3)

Comment: Was playing with dependency versions on the playground link and broke something.  Here's there new link to the playground: https://playcode.io/1765050

Comment: thank you both of you ... problem turned out to be something else but your answer still helped.